# Какова функция языка в данном сообщении? (2)

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Хотя Каспийское море и не имеет выхода к океану и по существу является озером, его считают морем за большие размеры водной поверхности.

Answer (score 2):

Это коммуникативная функция языка (функция общения), в данном случае язык использован для передачи информации.

Вариант редактирования:

*Хотя Каспийское море и не имеет выхода к океану и по существу является озером, его часто  называют морем **из-за** больших размеров водной поверхности.*